# What's wrong with UIColor *clr = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];?

Tags: iphone

```
UIColor *clr = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];
```

I have compiler errors at above line.

1. Expected ']' before numeric constant
2. 'UIColor' may not respond to '+colorWithRed:green:'

If I comment out that line, I don't have compiler error.

Maybe, I have this problem after I added below line in my Prefix.pch.

```
#define RGB(r, g, b) [UIColor colorWithRed:r/255.0 green:g/255.0 blue:b/255.0 alpha:1]
```

I had the same compiler errror. So, I deleted that line from .pch and I cleaned all target in build menu, and recompiled. I even rebooted. I retyped. It is useless.

Comment: The code is correct. The error must be in other line.

Comment: Actually, given the method signature that is in the "may not respond" message... I think CocoaFu is on to something... there is some strange character after "green"

Comment: Could you post more code? On my Mac compiles ok. Try to restart xCode. Remove the line and paste the code from your post.

Comment: Post the lines above the UIColor line.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely there is an extra character, possibly an invisible character after "green".  Try re-typing the line.  If that does not fix it, comment out the line to see if there are any other errors in the method/file.

If there are errors above the line, as above comment out the UIColor line and concentrate on them.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably somewhere else, that code looks totally fine.

Answer (score 1):

That line is fine.  Try looking around it.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
#define RGB(r, g, b) {return [UIColor colorWithRed:r/255.0 green:g/255.0 blue:b/255.0 alpha:1];}
```

Comment: I mean even if I don't use macro, I have compiler error. I deleted macro already.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem - I was getting "expected ]" and there was a little glyph  under one of the parameter names i.e. "green:". It turned out I had defined colours in the header i.e #define green 0x66ff99, and this caused the conflict and said error message with the use of  [UIColor colorWithRed: green: blue: alpha:].